# Topology of Renormalization group trajectories

Tags: quantum-field-theory, condensed-matter, renormalization, phase-transition, critical-phenomena

In [The renormalization group by Matthew Schwartz](http://www.waltervansuijlekom.nl/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/III-9-RenormalizationGroup_Schwartz.pdf) the is very interesting picture of RG for dimension and dimensionless couplings:

[image]

Topology of such diagrams is very different. But this pictures describe the same system.

**How from these pictures to understand, that these pictures describe the same system, but for different parametrisation of couplings?**

**Is it possible from some topological information from RG picture extract that this is the samr picture?**

**Or maybe some topological information is enough to restore initial theory?**

I also add another RG picture for this theory:

[image]